# EmberJs: render a template within a handlebars-helper into its parent element

Tags: templates, ember.js, rendering, handlebars.js

Because I have the name of a View inside a variable I'm using a handlebars helper to get it rendered.

So, I have an object as follows (all simplified of course)

```
config = Ember.Object.create({ view: "MyTplView"}) ;
```

Next, I have the following template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div id="container">
        {{helperViewRenderer config}}
    </div>
</script>
```

And the Handlebars helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('helperViewRenderer', function(value, options) {
    var template = App[value.view].create() ;
    template.appendTo("#container") ;
}) ;
```

The problem is that I try to insert the template into the element with id "container", which doesn't exist at that moment. What are the possibilities to fix this. For example, is it possible to get a HTML-string from the template and return this instead ?

Answer (score 2):

I have occasionally found it valuable to define a child view class inside of a parent view class instead of as a global. You can pass any path -- global or local -- to the `view` helper, and the current view is available as `view` in the current context. Thus,

```
App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("The parent's child: {{view view.ChildView}}."),

  ChildView: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("-- child view --")
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ember tries to go the route of creating 'outlets' through the use of the new router.

If you want to use the `appendTo` method then obviously you have to append your template to an existing HTML element. In that way, you can't get a HTML string from a template (unless you know it is part of a parent template). However if you're not too bothered about where you're inserting your template, then you can use a straight `append` which will add the template to the end of the body.

I think in your case it would be better to get familiar with the router, as you seem to be wanting to render different templates inside the same main template. Therefore you can easily separate these out by using the URL as a variable, and injecting the relevant view into the outlet.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route("index", { path: "/" });
  this.route("first", { path: "/view1" });
  this.route("another", { path: "/view2" });
});

App.FirstRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render('view1', { outlet: 'main' });
  }
});

App.AnotherRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render('view2', { outlet: 'main' });
  }
});
```

View:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div id="container">
        {{outlet main}}
    </div>
</script>
```

This way you don't need any handlebars helper passing in variables and it's all neatly wrapped up in Ember conventions.

Comment: Thnx for the reply. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwne8/5/) is a jsfiddle which somehow describes my situation. How would you apply your solution to this situation ?